# Why is Server Side Blazor not updating the textbox?

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-server-side, web-development-server

I have a simple form to collection user information. I want it to populate with my user's email when they open the form. For some reason it's not working despite being an extremely simple thing to do. I am using server side Blazor.

This is my textbox:

```
<input type="text" @bind="Email.ReplyTo"/>
```

And this is my OnInitializedAsync(), crucially User.Email has the string I expect, it's not null or blank or anything.

```
protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    Email.ReplyTo = User.Email;
}
```

Why is Blazor not updating the textbox?

Comment: what .net version are you using?

Comment: .NET Seven (Yes I had to spell out "seven" so SO would accept my comment, and I had to add more text after)

Comment: both lines of code after `Email.ReplyTo = User.Email;` is not required for this to work. Any console errors?

Comment: No console errors. It doesn't work with or without those two lines.

Comment: Try creating a new component with just this code in this [snippet](https://blazorfiddle.com/s/75bfb9d2), if that works then use your actual models.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is Blazor not updating the textbox?

Because there's more you aren't telling us!

Here's a *Minimal Reproducible Example* based on the little information provided in the question.

It works.

```cs
@page "/"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

<input class="form-control mb-3" type="text" @bind="_model.ReplyTo" />

<div class="alert alert-primary">
    @_model.ReplyTo
</div>
@code{
    private Email _model = new();
    private User _user = new("me@you.com");

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        // Pretend to get the data from somewhere
        await Task.Delay(10);
        _model.ReplyTo = _user.Email;
    }

    public record User(string Email);

    public class Email
    {
        public string ReplyTo { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use OnAfterRenderAsync Bacuse your DOM execute before OnInitializedAsync() method, Also You can use StateHasChanged() method after `Email.ReplyTo = User.Email;` but this not good.

```
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            Email.ReplyTo = User.Email;
        }
    }
```